# TypeError: this.func is not a function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a node.js application which uses functions from an imported JSON file. I also wanted to reuse some functions inside the file. I tried to access them with `this.functionName` but it just returns `TypeError: this.functionName is not a function`. Can someone explain why this occurs and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: The JSON format doesn't encode functions. There is no way to import them *as* JSON

Answer (score 0):

On another hand, if your function is a standard string you can do something like this, your function is in my case (x+1):

```js
var x=1;
var inc = eval('x + 1');
console.log(inc)
```